# A different statement for each for-loop iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, printf

I want to print a different statement for each iteration of a for-loop. I have tried assigning each statement to a variable, putting each variable in a vector and calling a different index of the vector for each iteration like this:

```
A = 1st statement
B = 2nd statement
C = 3rd statement

v = [A,B,C]

for i = 1:3
    fprintf('%s',v(i))
end
```

but it only prints the first statement one letter per iteration. What would be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `1xn` array, `n` alphabets will be stored. That is why you see first three letters getting printed (`i=1:3`). Assuming all the statements do not have the same length, you could save `A,B,C` in a cell array. Then access it as usual.

```
v={A;B;C};
for i = 1:size(v,1) %always try to use size(v,1) instead of hard-coding.
   fprintf('%s',v{i,1})
end
```

If all statements have the same length, then you have them in a matrix.

```
v=[A;B;C];
for i = 1:size(v,1) %always try to use size(v,1) instead of hard-coding.
   fprintf('%s',v(i,:))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following ...

```
A = '1st statement'
B = '2nd statement'
C = '3rd statement'

v = {A;B;C}

for i = 1:3
    fprintf('%s ',v{i,1}))
end
```

Note the use of `{;;;}` (cell array ... http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)

rather than `[,,,]`(matrix... http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html).

Comment: As @Parag mentions, hard coding the size of the array is a bad habit to pick up, unless you expect to have a specific number of elements!!